# Parse User Destroy - Javascript in Cloud Code

Tags: cloud

I've been trying to solve this issue for days now and I fear I'm in some sort of infinite loop. I'm trying to delete a user from the cloud code I have setup... using master key, etc etc. I've scoured through the docs, this forum, and everywhere else... with all answers sending me in circles.

Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteUser", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query("User");
query.equalTo("userId", request.params.user);
query.find({
    success: function(result) {
        query.destroy();
        response.success("success");
    },
    error: function(err,obj){
        response.error("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('deleteUser', function(request, response) {                                                                                      
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();                                                                                                                       
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);                                                                                                          
  query.get(request.params.objectId, {                                                                                                              
    success: function(user) {                                                                                                                       
      user.destroy({                                                                                                                                
        success: function() {                                                                                                                       
          response.success('User deleted');                                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                                                          
        error: function(error) {                                                                                                                    
          response.error(error);                                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                                                           
      });                                                                                                                                           
    },                                                                                                                                              
    error: function(error) {                                                                                                                        
      response.error(error);                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                               
  });                                                                                                                                               
});
```

Here is my CURL request:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APPLICATION_ID" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOUR_REST_API_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"objectId": "YOUR_OBJECT_ID"}' https://api.parse.com/1/functions/deleteUser
```